# How to do Android Accessibility for custom viewgroups

Tags: android, accessibility, viewgroup

1. I have a CustomViewGroup that extends from a ViewGroup.
2. In it I have 2 text views and 3, 4 different buttons that I inflate from different XML files.

My problem is that it does not seem to be accessible. What do I need to do at my end to see whats the problem?

Can you someone please point me to a good article or resource about accessibility ? The Androiid docs are very hard for me to follow. I am specifically looking for source code for extending ViewGRoups and using it.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You should check out the [Accessibility talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ld7kZRpMGb8) (and [slides](https://code.google.com/p/eyes-free/downloads/detail?name=501%20-%20Enabling%20Blind%20and%20Low-Vision%20Accessibility%20on%20Android.pdf) including step-by-step example code) from Google I/O 2013 as well as the documentation for the [ExploreByTouchHelper](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/ExploreByTouchHelper.html) class in the support library.

Comment: Does ExploreByTouchHelper  class also work with External Keyboard DPAD events ?