# How to set accessibility to circles drawn using Canvas?

Tags: android, accessibility

I have a custom view where in I'm drawing 6 circles using canvas in Android. Those circles act as Page indicators; which means that on the click of each circle (drawn using canvas), the different items are being displayed in a view pager. Now my requirement is to set individual focus to each circles and set different accessibility to each one. Please help. Thanks in advance.
Thanks,
Rakesh

Comment: You have to use on TouchListener and get cordinate after touch, and match these cordinates to them circle contains or not.

Comment: @Bansal, I have done that. Touchlistener works fine. Now my requirement is how to set accessibility to individual circles which I have drawn.

Comment: """and set different accessibility to each one""" what do you mean by `accessibility` here? something related to [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/accessibility/index.html)?

Comment: @pskink, Please refer this : https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/accessibility/apps.html
This is what I meant by accessibility. When TalkBack feature is turned ON in the phone, I need the focus to go to each circle (drawn using canvas) and speak out the text which I set as contectDescription.

Comment: so if you are drawing your circles on the `Canvas` then i assume you have your custom view, so read [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/accessibility/apps.html#custom-views)

Comment: @pskink, I have gone through this. When I tried this, I could only set the accessibility to the whole view, which contains all the 6 circles drawn using canvas. How do I set accessibility to the individual circles and gain individual focus?

Comment: how do you want to gain individual focus? are you using directional controller clicks?

Comment: @pskink , When you turn ON TalkBack in your device, you would be able to traverse through all of the actionable items in your phone. Eg: buttons, EditText etc. When the focus reaches each widget, it's contentDescription would be read out. Likewise I need those circles to be individually accessed with talkBack ON in the device. Please help!

Comment: if you want such "virtual" regions in your view them read: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/accessibility/apps.html#virtual-hierarchy

Comment: You can use `ExploreByTouchHelper`. See the answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24065375/how-to-do-android-accessibility-for-custom-viewgroups.

Comment: @alanv Do you happen to have a sample code or snippet to set accessibility to something which is drawn using canvas?

Comment: indeed, `ExploreByTouchHelper` is muuuuch more easier then using the low level accessibility API: its enough to implement 3 simple methods... `getVisibleVirtualViews`, `onPopulateNodeForVirtualView` and `getVirtualViewAt`

Comment: @pskink Ok. I'll try it out.

Comment: @alanv, It works like a charm buddy. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: @pskink, ExploreByTouchHelper does work. Thanks for your help man :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to use ExploreByTouchHelper to achieve my requirement as explained by @alanv and @pskink in the comment.

https://youtu.be/ld7kZRpMGb8?t=1196

Thanks guys!

Comment: You're a life saver

Comment: Does ExploreByTouchHelper class also work with External Keyboard DPAD events ?

Answer (score 0):

You should take position of the view with View.getX() and View.getY() to get x and y of the upper left corner and also assuming You know the radius (or able to obtain width/height of the view to determine radius). After that, obtain :

```
xTouch = MotionEvent.getX();
yTouch = MotionEvent.getY();
```

Then check the condition if:

```
     (xTouch - (x + radius)) * (xTouch - (x + radius)) + (yTouch - (y + radius)) * (yTouch - (y + radius)) <= radius * radius
```

The formula is just interpretation of schools geometry for determining if dot is inside circle area or not. Refer to circle equation for Cartesian coordinates for more details.

Values explanation is:

(x + radius) and (y + radius) is the center of circle.

(xTouch - (x + radius)) is distance from touch point to center by X.

(yTouch - (y + radius)) is distance from touch point to center by Y.

for the accessibility of the each circle and the accessibility text to be read it out if the TackBack is turned on then so the code for the complete scenario is:

```
package com.example.hello_world;

import java.util.Locale;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Paint.Style;
import android.graphics.Path;
import android.graphics.Path.Direction;
import android.graphics.RectF;
import android.graphics.Region;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech;
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech.OnInitListener;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnInitListener {
    String mText_To_Speach_text;
    private int MY_DATA_CHECK_CODE = 0;
    TextToSpeech myTTS;
    int initStatus = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(new MyView(this));

        Intent checkTTSIntent = new Intent();
        checkTTSIntent.setAction(TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_CHECK_TTS_DATA);
        startActivityForResult(checkTTSIntent, MY_DATA_CHECK_CODE);
    }

    class MyView extends View {

        private Path mPath, mPath2, mPath3, mPath4, mPath5;
        private Paint mPaint;
        private RectF mOval, mOval2;
        Region mRegion1, mRegion2, mRegion3, mRegion4, mRegion5, mRegion6;

        public MyView(Context context) {
            super(context);
            mPath = new Path();
            mPath2 = new Path();
            mPath3 = new Path();
            mPath4 = new Path();
            mPath5 = new Path();
            mPaint = new Paint();
            mPaint.setColor(0xffff0000);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
            mPath.reset();
            mPath.addCircle((w / 2) - 120, h / 2, 30, Direction.CW);
            mPath.close();

            mPath2.reset();
            mPath2.addCircle((w / 2) - 60, h / 2, 30, Direction.CW);
            mPath2.close();

            mPath3.reset();
            mPath3.addCircle(w / 2, h / 2, 30, Direction.CW);
            mPath3.close();

            mPath4.reset();
            mPath4.addCircle((w / 2) + 60, h / 2, 30, Direction.CW);
            mPath4.close();

            mPath5.reset();
            mPath5.addCircle((w / 2) + 120, h / 2, 30, Direction.CW);
            mPath5.close();

        }

        @Override
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            canvas.drawColor(0xffffffff);

            mPaint.setStyle(Style.FILL);
            canvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
            canvas.drawPath(mPath2, mPaint);
            canvas.drawPath(mPath3, mPaint);
            canvas.drawPath(mPath4, mPaint);
            canvas.drawPath(mPath5, mPaint);

            RectF rectF1 = new RectF();
            mPath.computeBounds(rectF1, true);
            mRegion1 = new Region();
            mRegion1.setPath(mPath, new Region((int) rectF1.left,
                    (int) rectF1.top, (int) rectF1.right, (int) rectF1.bottom));

            RectF rectF2 = new RectF();
            mPath2.computeBounds(rectF2, true);
            mRegion2 = new Region();
            mRegion2.setPath(mPath2, new Region((int) rectF2.left,
                    (int) rectF2.top, (int) rectF2.right, (int) rectF2.bottom));

            RectF rectF3 = new RectF();
            mPath3.computeBounds(rectF3, true);
            mRegion3 = new Region();
            mRegion3.setPath(mPath3, new Region((int) rectF3.left,
                    (int) rectF3.top, (int) rectF3.right, (int) rectF3.bottom));

            RectF rectF4 = new RectF();
            mPath4.computeBounds(rectF4, true);
            mRegion4 = new Region();
            mRegion4.setPath(mPath4, new Region((int) rectF4.left,
                    (int) rectF4.top, (int) rectF4.right, (int) rectF4.bottom));

            RectF rectF5 = new RectF();
            mPath5.computeBounds(rectF5, true);
            mRegion5 = new Region();
            mRegion5.setPath(mPath5, new Region((int) rectF5.left,
                    (int) rectF5.top, (int) rectF5.right, (int) rectF5.bottom));

        }

        @Override
        public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
            int x = (int) event.getX();
            int y = (int) event.getY();

            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                if (mRegion1.contains(x, y)) {
                    mText_To_Speach_text = "Circle1";
                    speakWords(mText_To_Speach_text);
                } else if (mRegion2.contains(x, y)) {
                    mText_To_Speach_text = "Circle2";
                    speakWords(mText_To_Speach_text);
                } else if (mRegion3.contains(x, y)) {
                    mText_To_Speach_text = "Circle3";
                    speakWords(mText_To_Speach_text);
                } else if (mRegion4.contains(x, y)) {
                    mText_To_Speach_text = "Circle4";
                    speakWords(mText_To_Speach_text);
                } else if (mRegion5.contains(x, y)) {
                    mText_To_Speach_text = "Circle5";
                    speakWords(mText_To_Speach_text);
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
    }

    private void speakWords(String speech) {
        myTTS.speak(speech, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
    }

    @Override
    public void onInit(int status) {
        if (initStatus == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
            if (myTTS.isLanguageAvailable(Locale.US) == TextToSpeech.LANG_AVAILABLE)
                myTTS.setLanguage(Locale.US);
        } else if (initStatus == TextToSpeech.ERROR) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Sorry! Text To Speech failed...",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == MY_DATA_CHECK_CODE) {
            if (resultCode == TextToSpeech.Engine.CHECK_VOICE_DATA_PASS) {
                myTTS = new TextToSpeech(this, this);
            } else {
                Intent installTTSIntent = new Intent();
                installTTSIntent
                        .setAction(TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_INSTALL_TTS_DATA);
                startActivity(installTTSIntent);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: onTouch works fine. Now I need each of those circles to be accessible when TalkBack is turned ON in Android device.Thanks!

Comment: My requirement here is to achieve accessibility. (Refer https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/accessibility/apps.html). I have a view where in I'm drawing 6 circles using canvas. Each of these 6 circles has onTouch as you mentioned above. Now my requirement is when I turn on TalkBack in the phone, when the user clicks on a particular circle, I need to set a focus to that circle and read out its accessibility text. How do I achieve this? And How do I set accessibility text to each of these circles drawn using canvas?

Comment: k @RAkeshH i got your point and just give me some time i am working on your pronblem only.. so see you soon at here..

Comment: Thanks buddy. I'm waiting for your help :)

Comment: @RakeshH i already answered what you need: [virtual view hierarchy](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/accessibility/apps.html#virtual-hierarchy)

Comment: @pskink, Can you please provide a code snippet? In my view, I'm drawing circles like: canvas.drawcircle(....). Can you please hint me how to set accessibility for these custom circles?

Comment: @pskink, In the sample activity, they're just asking us to do what needs to be done when that view is clicked.

Comment: Hii @RakeshH i got the solution for your querry so check my code i had updated the code

Comment: @pskink, Thanks buddy. I'll take a look and let you know.

Comment: @RakeshH just look at to the code i had posted and tell me that is it full filled your requirement or not

Comment: @kishansahu, The above doesn't help in getting the focus to each circles.

Comment: @kishansahu, I had to use ExplpreByTouchHelper to attain focus. Thanks a lot for your help :)